# How to display the exactly time from sensorevent.timestamp for Android?

Tags: java, android, time, sensors, android-dateutils

I want to display the time which the first step was detected. But the app always shows Jan 01 1970. Would some one check what is wrong and how to change it? Here is my code:

```
public void run() {
    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            long timeStamp = sensorEvent.timestamp / 1000000;
            textView_moveTime.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timeStamp));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    }, mSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

Comment: I think Jan 01 1970 equates to 0 (i.e. start of date/time). So perhaps look to see if 0 is being returned/set.

Comment: Since `timestamp` is nanosecond-level precision, it is unlikely to be in the Unix epoch timebase, so dividing by 1000000 is unlikely to work. It might be using the same system [as `nanoTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()), in which case you only use it for computing relative times from some starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

SensorEvent reports time in nanoseconds since system boot (including sleep time). 
To convert it to absolute time in nanos, use following formula:

```
(DateTime.now().getMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()) * 1000000
                + sensorEvent.timestamp
```

Comment: sorry, but what is "DateTime"... AS doesn't recognize this as a valid class of anything.

Comment: I guess, we can replace `DateTime.now().getMillis()` with `System.currentTimeMillis().`

Comment: The base of the `SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()` and `SensorEvent.timestamp` can be different (relative since boot) than the base of the `DateTime.now().getMillis()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` (wall clock time). Should it still work?

Comment: I have checked it, and it is working. However, I could not understand how and why because I guess the base of the `System.currentTimeMillis()` might be different than the base of the `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

Answer (score 0):

`SensorEvent.timestamp` is when the event happened, but it is an elapsed time since boot. It is not the exact timestamp of when the event happened. We want to get the actual time when the event happened from the elapsed time since the event happened.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#timestamp

1. We need all the entities in a similar unit. We are taking `Millis` here.
2. We have three entities to use. a) `System.currentTimeMillis()` b) `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and c) `SensorEvent.timestamp`

[image]

3. If we use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`, then we need to convert it into `Millis` as below:

```
val systemCurrentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
val systemClockElapsedRealtimeMillis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos())
val sensorEventTimeStampMillis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(sensorEvent.timestamp)
```

4. We need to find the difference between the `systemCurrentTimeMillis`, and `systemClockElapsedRealtimeMillis` as below:

[image]

```
val currentMinusElapsedRealtimeMillis = systemCurrentTimeMillis - systemClockElapsedRealtimeMillis
```

5. Once we find the difference, we need to add `sensorEventTimeStampMillis` to it as below:

[image]
OR
[image]

```
val actualEventTimeMillis = currentMinusElapsedRealtimeMillis + sensorEventTimeStampMillis
```

6. Then, we need to convert the result into UTC as below (I am using `Joda Time`):

```
val actualEventTimeUtc = DateTime(actualEventTimeMillis, DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

The `actualEventTimeUtc` is the absolute time when the event happened.

**Another way to understand it is:**

Suppose the sensor reports an event in `onSensorChanged.` We find that the current time is: 13 PM. In other words, the reporting time is 13 PM and it is not the time when the actual event happened.

The `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` says that it has been running since last 30 hours. In other words, it started 30 hours before from the current time.

So, we subtract the 30 hours from the current time to get the time when the sensor started. So, we get 7 AM of the previous day.

The `SensorEvent.timestamp` says that the event happened after 28 hours of the `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().`

Hence, we add 28 hours to the 7 AM of the previous day. So, we get 11 AM of the current day and it is the actual time when event happened.